# About root privilages for my application

Tags: application-development, gksu

Hello I am going to make certain application which requires root privileges to run.
I am using quickly for that application. How to use sudo , gksudo or anything else for that application to run?

Comment: Use of **sudo** would be Highly Recommended.

Comment: But I want to use it via my GUI

Comment: Policy Kit or GkSudo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the .desktop file you can put`gksudo yourprogram` or you can write a script that will launch your program using gksudo (maybe a bash script).

**Edit**: You can also write the portion of code that needs root separately and run it as a seperate process using gksudo when you need it.